# Update the value of object reference

Tags: c++, reference

I have a function as below. I tried to change the value of object reference to a new object by using `dir = Directory(path);` but I got a compilation error as below. Any advice? Also is this a good way to do this?

> Error C2280   'Directory &Directory::operator =(const Directory &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

```
class Directory
{
public:
    const fs::path path;
    Directory *parent;
    std::vector<Directory *> sub_dir;
    std::vector<File *> files;

    Directory(const fs::path path, Directory *parent = NULL);
    double const deltaBase = .001;

    Directory(const Directory&) = default;
    Directory& operator=(const Directory&) = default;

    std::string getDirName(void);
};

void create_imgui_window(ImGui::FileBrowser *fileDialog, const char *label, char path[MAX_PATH_LENGTH], Directory &dir)
{
    // (optional) set browser properties
    fileDialog->SetTitle("Browse");

    ImGui::Begin(label);
    IMGUI_LEFT_LABEL(ImGui::InputText, "Path", path, MAX_PATH_LENGTH);
    if (ImGui::IsItemHovered() && path[0])
        ImGui::SetTooltip(path);
    ImGui::SameLine();
    if (ImGui::Button("Browse"))
        fileDialog->Open();

    create_directory_tree(dir);

    ImGui::End();

    fileDialog->Display();

    if (fileDialog->HasSelected())
    {
        strcpy_s(path, MAX_PATH_LENGTH, fileDialog->GetSelected().string().c_str());
        std::cout << "Selected directory: " << path << std::endl;
    
        dir = Directory(path);

        fileDialog->ClearSelected();
    }
}
```

Final Answer: Remove the const on `fs::path path;`

```
class Directory
{
public:
    fs::path path;
    Directory *parent;
    std::vector<Directory *> sub_dir;
    std::vector<File *> files;

    Directory(const fs::path path, Directory *parent = NULL);

    Directory& operator=(const Directory&) = default;

    std::string getDirName(void);
};
```

Comment: Look at the error "attempting to reference a _deleted_ function" Creator of `Directory` decided it shouldn't be assigned. Post code of `Directory` might help.

Comment: `double const deltaBase = .001;` this looks to me like it shouldnt be a member variable, i would suggest defining this constant elsewhere or make it static, this would likely avoid the issue youre having

Comment: Some stylistic/design points: 1. please don't mix member variables with member functions, it's horrible to read 2. raw pointers as member variables are often candidates for `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask your copy-assignment operator to be implicitly defined:

```
Directory& operator=(const Directory&) = default;
```

Meanwhile you have `const` data members:

```
const fs::path path; // Consider omitting the const here
const double deltaBase = .001; // Seems like a candidate for a static member
```

The synthesized *(implicitly defined)* copy-assignment operator [defined as deleted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) if a class has **a data member that is `const`** or a reference *(or if the class has a data member that has a deleted or inaccessible copy-assignment operator on its own)*.

Consider two approaches:

- The non-`const` `path` data member, as well as `deltaBase` not being `const` inside each `Directory` instance.
- Making the `create_imgui_window` function to return a `Directory`, instead of modifying one.